# What Qualifies as Trimmable Deadweight in a Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there any reason (not to) delete unused auto-generated .css/.js/_helper.rb files in a Rails app? I'm about to get rid of some for simple cleanliness purposes and want to make sure that I'm not breaking anything or going against Rails Best Practices I don't know about.

A [variety](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=cleaning+up+a+rails+app&oq=cleaning+up+a+rails+app&gs_l=hp.3...132.4355.0.4555.31.24.0.4.4.0.174.2431.14j10.24.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.2.hp.Tk9q5Ts8rPI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42261806,d.cGE&fp=cecfd734039d8d45&biw=916&bih=592) [of](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=removing+rails+deadweight&oq=removing+rails+deadweight&gs_l=serp.3..33i21.560333.565471.0.565538.27.23.1.3.3.0.162.2061.15j7.22.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.2.serp.ktl5g9dqNWk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=cecfd734039d8d45&biw=1281&bih=592) [Google searches](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=rails+remove+unused+js&oq=rails+remove+unused+js&gs_l=serp.3...5475.7342.2.8147.3.3.0.0.0.0.116.295.1j2.3.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.2.serp.yliZ0l47iOk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=cecfd734039d8d45&biw=1281&bih=592) weren't particularly fruitful on this one (results tended towards tools for discovering which js functions / css classes weren't being used), so I hope you guys forgive the slightly opinionated nature of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as Im aware there is no reason you cannot , If there is a css/js file that is auto generated and I am not using it then i delete it. Sometimes I get files like this generated folders.css.scss, dont use it so i get rid of it.

As for the helper files then again, if you don't use then you can remove.

This is all in my opinion and experience and of course if anyone has a different view then please share